# Calculate minimum sample size for Fleiss Kappa

Tags: agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

Can you please explain to me how to calculate a minimum sample size (rated subjects) for Fleiss Kappa? I cannot find neither calculators to do this, nor some reference values.
Thank you very much.

G

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Sample size to do what? It seems like you can calculate the value for just one annotation: either they agree or do not agree. Would this mean that your minimum sample size required is one?